Some keys refuse to work after suspend or reboot, then work ok after a few minutes
#Azus #Zenbook UX325, new Ubuntu 24.04 (fresh new install in july), using Ubuntu for a whole year on this laptop (with no major trouble). All the  last updates have been applied.
Running kernel 6.8.0.44 at the time of this post.
Since a few weeks I noticed I had more and more troubles logging in to my Gnome session, because some keys (used in my password) didn't work well while typing my password. First I thought it was a hardware trouble with my keyboard even if the laptop is just two years old... But after a while all the keys are responsive and I can use my system as usual.
Then I thought it was a trouble with GDM3, but even without it, the trouble is still here when I start the computer or when I resume from suspend.
It got worse these last days: now the keyboard only works as expected after more than 10 mn waiting for all the keys to "come back".
AFAIK, It's always the same keys that are "stuck" : 2, z, q, s, w, x, Fn (I couldn't find other keys "missing", I use an AZERTY keyboard).
I have absolutely no idea how to fix it because I don't know what is happening! I noticed some "hangs up" while it's happening, very subtle but noticeable.
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i keyboard
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
N: Name="ASUE140A:00 04F3:3134 Keyboard"

Update November 30th, 2024
System updated to 24.10 in august. Seemed to be fixed for a few weeks, then it suddenly appeared once again.
I'm almost certain it's not a hardware issue with my keyboard, because when my keys work, it works flawlessly, and for a long time (that is, until I suspend or reboot the system).
I noticed another bug that could be related: when I unplug the laptop from its power cable, the whole Gnome experience becomes somewhat sluggish.
Sometimes the identified keys are not responsive for more that 3 or 4 minutes and suddenly it comes back. When it does, I noticed that for a few moments, it tends to print 2 or 3 times the key after one push on it. For example, it prints "exxample" instead of "example". Happens in all the editors I tested, from Libre Office to GEdit to Gnome Terminal to my browser itself.
I think I'm about to rip my entire disk and proceed to install a new system once again. Maybe not Ubuntu this time?
FYI, the GRUB arguments, supposed to fix the trouble, actually don't fix it at all, according to my experiments (so I deleted the comments I made about it under this question). Arguments tested are i8042dumbkbd, i8042=1, i8042.nomux, i8042.nopnp and i8042.noloop. And yes, I didn't forget to run grub-update each time.

Update: it WAS a hardware trouble. I changed the keyboard of the laptop and after two weeks, everything is working alright now.
