Keyboard Few Keys Don't Work
I use Lubuntu.
Few keys of my keyboard stopped suddenly working.
I have tried rebooting , reinstalling and nothing helped.
Once I was able to to fix the problem with resetting the keyboard shortcuts.
However , after the lid off hibernate\sleep. the problem came back.
It never happened before Playing around with the Keyboard Tweaks and Keyboard Shortcuts Settings.
IT AFFECTS BIOS AND LEGACY AND GRUB TOO.
WHEN I HAVE FIXED THAT WITH RESETTING THE KEYBOARD SHORTCUTS IT HAS FIXED BIOS AND LEGACY AND GRUB TOO.
I HAVE TRIED UPGRADING ALL OF MY DRIVERS.
Funny and Strange things that happen:
*) Another thing that occurs is when I press “number 2 key” or “number 1 key” they don’t work .
but When I press escape+num 2+num 1 it prints out a special char. “<”
xev:

KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x2e9, subw 0x0, time 14467569, (539,-373), root:(1345,215),
    state 0x10, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
    root 0x2e9, subw 0x0, time 14467699, (539,-373), root:(1345,215),
    state 0x10, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

*) Funny thing is that when keyboard was working good. the caps lock key light was not going on when the Caps Lock was on. Now when I use Onboard and press Caps lock the light goes on but Caps Lock doesn’t work as a key.
Can you please help me to solve the problem?
Solutions that I have tried:
*) I have tried Windows Troubleshooter. Found none.
*) I have tried updating and Uninstall+Reinstalling the PS2 Keyboard Driver.
Nothing has changed.
*) I have tried contacting Chickony or Dell, None was succesful.
Chickony support is unreachable .
Dell community and support depend on Warranty and they don’t really care.
*) I have updated the BIOS. non has changed.
*) I have read about linux kernel and its modules. I have tried modifying some changes and changing to HK locale or others. Installing Chinese support programs. and other input control programs.
None helped.
*) I have of course removed and reconnected keyboard from connector. Nothing has changed.
*) I have opened 2 keys individually to see if maybe some dust or other cause.
Well there was a really small amount of dust but removing+cleaning didn’t help.
*) I have tried different Operation Systems .
No results.
The only solution that once had worked is resetting the Keyboard Shortcuts via PureOS settings it worked like magic until suspend.
Nowadays it is not helping.
*) I have tried reinstalling PureOs.
none is changed.
*) I have tried removing and reinstalling CMOS battery.
It has fixed the bipping on startup. not the keyboard…
*) I am trying to reset the VRAM but I have no Idea how to do that.
*) I have tried battery removing and pressing sleep button for 60secs or more.

Your details are somewhat difficult to follow, you mention Lubuntu, but gave no release details (or install media which would tell us what kernel stack you're using which maybe useful for some releases), then you mention windows but its unclear if it worked there or not, then switched to Pure OS, which was then re-installed; so are you using Lubuntu now?   If you have the same problem in windows, Pure OS & previously in Lubuntu, your issue is hardware related & not OS specific.

My main use today is LUbuntu 24.04 I am not familiar with the command that provides all of the information that is required for you.
I had Windows build in my pc When I have Bought it.
Last year I have started Using Linux Mint - Everything was fine with Keyboard.
This was my first Linux Distro.
Later I wanted to try other Distros such as Ubuntu, Debian, SliTaz  , trisquel , Arch, Fedora and PureOS...
I have been configuring settings in PureOS when this problem occurred first.
I think that it is related to the Layout.
My keyboard model is: "built in" chickony mb-13N73HB-422

This is clearly a hardware and not an OS issue.

How is it possible then that when I press ESC+2 it works but when I press only 2 it doesn't. How is it possible that resetting the Keyboard shortcuts fix this issue?
Why is my Keyboard Looks like new?
How is that few days after few more keys have stopped working and since than none are stopping to work.

Seems quite similar to the bugs I had with my Asus Zenbook... What is your laptop brand and model please?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526366/some-keys-refuse-to-work-after-suspend-or-reboot-then-work-ok-after-a-few-minut/1530620

Dell Inspiron 3542 ;\
